# Unnecessary post locking

Tags: discussion, moderation, comments

@Andrei, your locking of [this post](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/2531/199) was unnecessary and premature, given the reason you stated. The first comment I made was exactly as SE suggests when downvoting. The remaining three hardly constitute a "high amount", especially since it was clear the discussion was over (Lee didn't seem receptive to what I'd said, so I left it at that.)

I would have taken this to chat as the lock message suggests but for some technical reason I cannot login to chat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe Andrei locked the post because it seemed likely to spark an extended conflict in the comments. His instinct was correct, although I don't think the pre-emptive lock was the right way to deal with it. As such I have unlocked the post.

That said, I'm also deleting the irrelevant comments. From [the Help Center guidance about commenting](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment):

> #### When should I comment?
>
> You should submit a comment if you want to:
>
> - **Request clarification from the author**;
> - Leave **constructive criticism** that guides the author in improving the post;
> - Add relevant but minor or transient information to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated).
>
> #### When *shouldn't* I comment?
>
> Comments are not recommended for any of the following:
>
> - Suggesting corrections that don't *fundamentally* change the meaning of the post; instead, [make](/help/editing) or [suggest](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work) an edit;
> - Answering a question or providing an alternate solution to an existing answer; instead, post an actual answer (or edit to expand an existing one);
> - Compliments which do not add new information ("+1, great answer!"); instead, up-vote it and [pay it forward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer);
> - **Criticisms which do not add anything constructive** ("-1, see previous comments you scallywag!"); instead, down-vote (and provide or up-vote a better answer if appropriate);
> - **Secondary discussion or debating a controversial point**; please use chat instead;
> - **Discussion of community behavior or site policies**; please use meta instead.

(Emphasis mine.)

In summary:

- Andrei's instincts were correct, but he used a jackhammer where a trowel was needed;
- Explaining the reason for a downvote in the comments is perfectly acceptable, but;
- Comments should not be used for secondary discussions or site policy.

Comment: (Andrei's instincts were correct,...)  I agree. It was the jackhammerness that I was flagging, not the principle of the thing. (Comments should not be used for secondary discussions...) OK, understood.

Comment: Got it boss. Should I have instead commented like "Ok folks, take a deep breath"?

Comment: Something like that @AndreiVolkov, or just clean up the comments (and leave your own comment explaining why you did so). Locking is for a situation where the post just won't stop attracting the wrong kind of attention, lasting more than several hours and amassing tens of comments, etc.

Comment: Understood. Somehow I was hesitant to delete comments...

Comment: Having ones comments disappear is a good thing. (I've seen some of my comments get deleted for the better) Sort of like a zen monk getting wacked with a stick to get them to focus again.